# How to store the data from Firefox extension into my local system disk

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, dom-events, firefox-addon-webextensions, selenium-firefoxdriver

I have an data which I get it from Firefox extension using selenium. I don't know How to write the data into my system local disk? Please help me if anyone knows

Comment: Extensions can't write directly to arbitrary local files. You can download a file into the standard downloads directory or use [nativeMessaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging) to call a separate utility that will store the file.

Comment: Nice information will try it